# Tradução de "press" deveria ser "imprensa"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

No rodapé do site tem um link para `https://stackoverflow.com/company/press` com o texto "Pressione".

[image]

Nesse caso, deveria ser "Imprensa" ou algo do gênero.

Comment: Essa parte o pessoal traduziu meio com press.

Comment: ["Mas já tem gente vendo que você não press"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsdGmDnNdrE)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tava feio isso, hein? Corrigi no transifex, vamos ver se corrige no site até amanhã.

**UPDATE 2017-12-20**

"Até amanhã" foi muito otimismo meu. Mas a equipe do SO aprovou minha revisão e hoje a correção finalmente entrou no ar.

Comment: Precisa "pressionar" o pessoal, pq continua com problema (ao menos aqui no Meta: https://i.stack.imgur.com/boo43.png) - Quem sabe na próxima a gente encontre algum botão [imprensa] no site.

Comment: Está feito.....